# Relationship between current and magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics, electromagnetic-induction

If 2 pieces of iron are next to each other, there is no magnetic attraction. However if a current is run through them, they will behave as magnets. My question is is there a relationship between the amount of current passing through them and the attraction they feel towards each other? Please include sources and perhaps the name of this phenomenon with your answer
Thanks

Comment: I think this question is not trivial. I can not answer this question as this is on hold. Please read something on magnetic circuit you will get the answers, but it will take few days to totally grasp the concepts.

Comment: Hello, can you suggest a certain book or website to get me started?

Comment: Hi, I have read several books to solve this problem while I was planning to design a solenoid valve. I could not pin point from where I have made my notes but one good book is "magnetic fundamentals" by Etienne du Tremolet de Lacheisserie, Damien gignoux, Michel Schlenker published by springer. Chapter 2.1.5 has magnetic circuit approximation. You may find at least some starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there would be an electromagnetic force acting between the two current carrying iron bars.  This is similar to the way the unit the ampere is formally defined.  From the Wikipedia article on the [ampere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere)

> [Ampère's force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law) states that there is an attractive or repulsive force between two parallel wires carrying an electric current. This force is used in the formal definition of the ampere, which states that the ampere is the constant current that will produce an attractive force of $2 × 10^{−7}$ newtons per metre of length between two straight, parallel conductors of infinite length and negligible circular cross section placed one metre apart in a vacuum.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Also, about ampere's theorem, does the fact that the wires are made of iron influence the magnetic field that each one would feel?

Comment: That I don't have a good answer for - you might want to pose it as another question.